# Exceprt not displaying

Tags: loop

I am using a custom template homepage in which I want to display some excerpt from a category but it's not displaying as I code for just `the_excerpt`. I have a confusion too, they say the `the_excerpt` should be used within loop. What is the main reason of loop? As my code is wrapped within the loop, am i missing something?

Comment: Code missing a closing semicolon for closing statement in PHP in the first line. Just put a semicolon at the end of `the_post();`. And `endif` has a wrong "php" constant before it. Or, it's just a typo! :)

Comment: @MayeenulIslam sorry i missed semicolon when editing my code here as well as php, i have the semicolon in my code but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post the whole code of your template file please?

Comment: @iEmanuele sure, [here](http://pastebin.aquilenet.fr/?a0289f373a03b2e0#kXjxE+FerT9/+sJ7GymI6K5/74qgYlyIAyvSuP1v58w=)

Comment: your code looks just fine, i've tested it and it works

Comment: but my excerpt, don't show up :-/ how can i check/debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question:

> What is the main reason of loop?

the clearest answer comes from official documentation:

> The Loop is PHP code used by WordPress to display posts. Using The
> Loop, WordPress processes each post to be displayed on the current
> page, and formats it according to how it matches specified criteria
> within The Loop tags. Any HTML or PHP code in the Loop will be
> processed on each post.
>
> When WordPress documentation says "This tag must be within The Loop",
> such as for specific Template Tag or plugins, the tag will be repeated
> for each post.

It's correct put within the loop `the_excerpt()` [template tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags).

For example a loop code it might looks like:

```
<?php if( have_posts() ) : while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
  <p>No posts were found</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

To help you with your issue, it could be a good idea posting the whole code

Comment: i did. pls have a look.

Comment: @AmmarKhan, if you change the template tag from `the_excerpt()` to `the_title()` what's happen?

Comment: `the_title` shows title but `the_excerpt` doesn't show excerpt. yes i have excerpt in my backend.

Comment: very very strange, have you tried to disable the plugins installed or change the theme?

Comment: yes, but can i debug it? like print_r or var_dump? if yes, how?

Comment: I do not know how else to help you, try to verify that in the file `functions.php` there are not some strange filter function on `the_excerpt`.
With [this](http://pastebin.com/nJNYYF6z) you can get a list of all registered filter functions for a given hook

Comment: @AmmarKhan: what if you use `the_content()` instead of `the_excerpt()`? Do that work?

Comment: @MayeenulIslam nothing get displayed. only `the_title()` work. here is my code, maybe i am doing something wrong?
`if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
   the_title();
endwhile;
endif;

Comment: @AmmarKhan have you checked your functions.php file to see if there are some filter function for `the_excerpt` or for `the_content`?

Comment: @iEmanuele i have a child theme and functions.php has nothing in it.

Comment: please, check functions.php also in parent theme or use [this](http://pastebin.com/nJNYYF6z) to print all registered filter for given hook.